# getting Error while working with MODI

Tags: c#-4.0

Error Message :

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {56F963EC-6EFC-4A6B-9A1E-5BFE545C89D0} failed due to the following error:
80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

Code:

```
MODI.Image mi = new MODI.Image(_img);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the com library's registration has gone awry on windows.
Go to the directory where the concerned dll is placed
and try executing the command in administrative mode

regsvr32 TheConcernedLibrary.dll

and then try.